# Unexpected result while using lowess to smooth a data.table column in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I have a data.table `test_dt` in which I want to smooth the y column using `lowess` function.

```
test_dt <- structure(list(x = c(28.75, 30, 31.25, 32.5, 33.75, 35, 36.25, 
37.5, 38.75, 40, 41.25, 42.5, 43.75, 45, 46.25, 47.5, 48.75, 
50, 52.5, 55, 57.5, 60, 62.5, 63.75, 65, 67.5, 70, 72.5, 75, 
77.5, 80, 82.5, 85, 87.5, 90, 92.5, 95, 97.5, 100, 102.5, 103.75, 
105, 106.25, 107.5, 108.75, 110, 111.25, 112.5, 113.75, 115, 
116.25, 117.5, 118.75, 120, 121.25, 122.5, 125, 130, 135, 140, 
145), y = c(116.78, 115.53, 114.28, 113.05, 111.78, 110.53, 109.28, 
108.05, 106.78, 105.53, 104.28, 103.025, 101.775, 100.525, 99.28, 
98.05, 96.8, 95.525, 93.1, 90.65, 88.225, 85.775, 83.35, 82.15, 
80.9, 78.5, 76.075, 73.675, 71.25, 68.85, 66.5, 64.075, 61.725, 
59.4, 57.075, 54.725, 52.475, 50.225, 48, 45.75, 44.65, 43.55, 
42.475, 41.45, 40.35, 39.275, 38.25, 37.225, 36.175, 35.175, 
34.175, 33.225, 32.275, 31.3, 30.35, 29.45, 27.625, 24.175, 21, 
18.125, 15.55), z = c(116.778248424972, 115.531456655985, 114.284502467544, 
113.034850770519, 111.784500981402, 110.533319511795, 109.284500954429, 
108.034850457264, 106.784502297216, 105.531265565238, 104.278221015846, 
103.026780249377, 101.775992395759, 100.528761292272, 99.2853168637851, 
98.043586202838, 96.8021989104315, 95.5702032427799, 93.1041279347743, 
90.6575956222915, 88.2179393348852, 85.783500434839, 83.3503011023971, 
82.136280706039, 80.922846825298, 78.4965179152157, 76.0823895453039, 
73.6686672097464, 71.264486719796, 68.8702598156142, 66.4865368523571, 
64.1182523898466, 61.7552221811808, 59.4004347738795, 57.0823289450761, 
54.7908645949795, 52.5071096685879, 50.2308279167219, 47.9940967492558, 
45.7658417529877, 44.6514226583931, 43.5622751034012, 42.4876666190815, 
41.4173110074806, 40.3555584369672, 39.3004471381618, 38.2552969838653, 
37.2202353638959, 36.1963659189447, 35.1889616530209, 34.2004259883859, 
33.2295174626826, 32.2669278456991, 31.3171387914754, 30.3742375589802, 
29.4555719783757, 27.6243725086786, 23.9784367995753, 27.625, 
27.625, 27.625)), row.names = c(NA, -61L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

As can be seen in the image below, I am getting an unexpected result. The expected result is that the line (`z` column) in the graph below should closely follow the points (`y` column).

[image: Smoothing using lowess]

Here is my code -

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
test_dt[, z := lowess(x = x, y = y, f = 0.1)$y]
ggplot(test_dt) + geom_point(aes(x, y)) + geom_line(aes(x, z))
```

Q1. Can someone suggest why `lowess` is not smoothing properly?

Q2. Since `lowess` is not working as expected, is there any other function in R that would be more efficient in smoothing the `y` column without producing a spike (as `lowess` did on the boundary points)?

Comment: Was it intended to use ```geom_line(aes(x, z))``` instead of   ```geom_line(aes(x, y))``` ?

Comment: When you say "more efficient in solving this problem", what "problem" are you talking about exactly? It doesn't seem like your points need much smoothing. Smoothing is always difficult on the boundary of your observed data.

Comment: I want to smooth the ```y``` column so that all y points fall on a smooth line.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the very small span (0.1) that you're using.  If you try f=1/4 or f=1/3, the smoothed lines is much nice

Comment: Also, if you use test_dt[, z := loess(y ~ x, span = 0.1)$y] , you'll get a nice smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `loess` instead:

```r
test_dt[, z := predict(loess(y ~ x, data = test_dt))]

ggplot(test_dt) + geom_point(aes(x, y)) + geom_line(aes(x, z))
```

[image]

Note though, that if all you want to do is plot the line, this is exactly the method that `geom_smooth` uses, so without even creating a `z` column, you could do:

```r
ggplot(test_dt, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved by keeping the number of iterations to zero.`lowess` acts like `loess` when iterations are kept at zero.

```
test_dt[, z := lowess(x = x, y = y, f = 0.1, iter=0)$y]
```